# Group count by the hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I am exploring bike share data. I combined a bike share table with a weather data table.
I would like to see the count of bike trips for every hour, based on the weather time.

[image]

I have tried

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add a part of your dataframe here as text so others can replicate it. Also, show us what you've tried so far. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AshutoshPorwal I appreciate the feedback. I asked an improved version of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019244/counts-of-rows-per-hour

Comment: Appreciate the efforts!