# Counts of rows per hour

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science, etl

I am exploring bike share data.

I combined two tables: one containing bike share data and the other containing weather data. The 'Date Start' column is in the bike share data. The 'date' column is in the weather data.

I would like to group the count of ID for each hour, so I can see the effect of weather on bike usage.

| ID | Start | End | Date Start | Duration | date | rain | temp | wdsp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1754125 | Eyre Square South | Glenina | 01 Jan 2019 00:17 | 00:15:02 | 01-jan-2019 00:00 | 0.0 | 9.9 | 4.0 |
| 1754170 | Brown Doorway | University Hospital Galway | 01 Jan 2019 07:55 | 00:04:57 | 01-jan-2019 01:00 | 0.0 | 9.3 | 4.0 |
| 1754209 | New Dock Street | New Dock Street | 01 Jan 2019 11:42 | 02:57:57 | 01-jan-2019 02:00 | 0.0 | 9.2 | 5.0 |
| 1754211 | Claddagh Basin | Merchants Gate | 01 Jan 2019 11:50 | 00:02:43 | 01-jan-2019 03:00 | 0.0 | 9.1 | 5.0 |

I have tried:

```
data.groupby(['date','ID']).size()
data.groupby(['date','ID']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

But I don't really know what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to be able to count the rows by ID, Date and hour, so you can do this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date Start'].dt.normalize()
df['hour'] = df['Date Start'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

to get the dates and full hours:

```
     ID              Start                         End          Date Start  \
0  1754125  Eyre Square South                     Glenina 2019-01-01 00:17:00   
1  1754170      Brown Doorway  University Hospital Galway 2019-01-01 07:55:00   
2  1754209    New Dock Street             New Dock Street 2019-01-01 11:42:00   
3  1754211     Claddagh Basin              Merchants Gate 2019-01-01 11:50:00   

   Duration              date  rain  temp  wdsp       Date  hour  
0  00:15:02  2019-01-01 00:00   0.0   9.9   4.0 2019-01-01     0  
1  00:04:57  2019-01-01 01:00   0.0   9.3   4.0 2019-01-01     7  
2  02:57:57  2019-01-01 02:00   0.0   9.2   5.0 2019-01-01    11  
3  00:02:43  2019-01-01 03:00   0.0   9.1   5.0 2019-01-01    11
```

and then use group by:

```
df.groupby(['ID','Date','hour']).size()
```

which returns

```
ID        Date        hour
1754125  2019-01-01  0       1
1754170  2019-01-01  7       1
1754209  2019-01-01  11      1
1754211  2019-01-01  11      1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Perhaps my intial question was not clear. I would like a count of bicycle trips for every hour of 2019. I have 27109 bike trips in 2019 and there are 8760 hours in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar project using the london bike riding data.  I parse_dates in the csv then used the timestamp as an index and retrieved the datetime parts

```
df=pd.read_csv('london_merged.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col="timestamp")
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df['day_of_month'] = df.index.day
df['day_of_week'] = df.index.dayofweek
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['date']=df.index.date
print(df)

filter=df['year']==2019
df[filter].groupby(['hour']).size()
```

Comment: Perhaps my intial question was not clear. I would like a count of bicycle trips for every hour of 2019. I have 27109 bike trips in 2019 and there are 8760 hours in 2019.